# @font-face generated in php using get_option returns 404 not found for font file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am fairly new to WordPress theme development and am currently developing a theme. I want to implement some font options where the user can customize the font properties (font size, font weight, and so on...). For that, a font file can be uploaded by a form on a settings page.

The font file is successfully uploaded to a fonts folder inside the theme's folder, and the @font-face css is correctly printed in the browser, but I am unable to get the file through @font-face using get_option, which is always returning a 404 error on the console.

This is my @font-face/css function:

```
function ld_output_custom_fonts() {
  $font = esc_attr(get_option("hh_font_name"));
  echo "
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: '{$font}';
      src: url('fonts/{$font}.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('fonts/{$font}.woff') format('woff');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }

    h1, h2 {
      font-family: '{$font}';
    }
  </style>
  ";
}
```

Things I already tried:

- tested the uploaded font in @font-face directly on static CSS (it works);
- called the function using wp_enqueue_scripts (it doesn't work);
- called the function inside wp_head (it doesn't work);

What am I missing?
There is a special way to call the files since is not static CSS?
Thank you in advance (:

Comment: I am guessing that `url('fonts/{$font}.woff2')` most likely is not the correct URL. Remember that relative URLs in CSS, are relative _to_ the location of the CSS. For an external stylesheet, that would be the stylesheet's own URL; if you output a `style` element into your HTML, it is the URL of that HTML document.

Comment: my files are:

theme folder > style.css (for css) and theme folder > fonts > font files (for the font file). I tested using `./fonts/` and also `../fonts/ ` to try to get the correct paths, but didn't work

Comment: solved using get_theme_file_uri(); on the file path. thank you (: